# NSWindow Location

Tags: swift, macos, nswindow

I am programmatically creating a window that needs to span across 2 screens. the size of the window being created is correct but the window is starting about halfway across the first screen. I can drag it back to the beginning of the first screen and the NSWindow fits perfectly.

I just need to know where I'm going wrong in terms of the starting point for the window.

```
    func createNewWindow() {
    let bannerWidth = NSScreen.screens[0].frame.width * 2
    let bannerHeight = NSScreen.screens[0].frame.height
    let rect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0,y :0), size: CGSize(width: bannerWidth, height: bannerHeight))
    let newWindow = NSWindow(contentRect: rect, styleMask: [.closable], backing: .buffered, defer: false)
    let storyboard = NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateController(withIdentifier: "ExternalScreen") as? NSViewController
    let window = storyboard?.view
    newWindow.styleMask.update(with: .resizable)

    NSMenu.setMenuBarVisible(false)
    newWindow.title = "New Window"
    newWindow.isOpaque = false
    newWindow.isMovableByWindowBackground = true
    newWindow.backgroundColor = NSColor(calibratedHue: 0, saturation: 1.0, brightness: 0, alpha: 0.7)
    newWindow.toggleFullScreen(true)
    newWindow.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
    newWindow.toolbar?.isVisible = false
    newWindow.contentView?.addSubview(window!)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're setting the content rectangle, but not setting the frame. The frame is the rectangle that the window occupies in *screen coordinates*. To move the window, you can `setFrameOrigin()` or `setFrameTopLeftPoint()`.

Comment: The content rect is also in screen coordinates.